# KDE and Multi-Monitor, how to have program started on the screen it was opened from

Tags: kde-plasma, multiple-monitors

I have been trying KDE and customized it enough to my liking. I added panels and application launchers on each screen and windows opened shows on each screen panel.

But whenever I start an application either from the "start menu" or from the quick launch, it position on any screen.

Is there a way to have application started on the screen it was opened?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After spending too much time in settings, google, and Window Rules, I finally found my answer.

In System Settings -> Window Behavior -> Window Behavior -> Focus Tab
enable the box "Active screen follows mouse"